# Node.js Web and Mobile apps - Where to read excel file?

Tags: node.js, excel, mobile, architecture

I'm starting with node js and I was trying to build a web application and a mobile app too. My idea was building a Node API and then create a web app (maybe using Angular) and an Android App. One of the main functionalities will be loading data from an excel file using the web app, processing this data and then show some info both in the web app and the mobile app.

I'm not sure if this is the best way to go.. how could I send the excel file from the web app to the node API and then read the file and process it? I have seen several node packages to read excel files, that's not the problem. I just don't know how to pass the excel to the API from my web app.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to send multipart/form-data via a POST. Then you can access your data in the node.js app. There's plenty of info's on how to send multipart/form-data on the web.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try doing it that way.